# Using JRJC, how do I assign a ticket?

Tags: java, jira

I am trying to automatically assign a ticket using JRJC 4.0.0.

I am using this:

```
  final Map<String, FieldInput> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put("assignee", new FieldInput("assignee", "XXXX"));
  a_conn.getIssueClient().updateIssue(this.m_key, new IssueInput(map)).claim();
```

But I get this error:

> [ErrorCollection{status=400, errors={assignee=data was not an object}, errorMessages=[]}]

Anyone already know the solution? I tried searching here in SO but can't find anything that works.

Answer (score 0):

```
  final IssueInputBuilder is = new IssueInputBuilder();
  is.setAssigneeName(a_username);
  a_conn.getIssueClient().updateIssue(this.m_key, is.build()).claim();
```